# Sed to extract with log between to given date

Tags: linux, shell, variables, if-statement, scripting

I am trying to extract the logs b/w two given dates. the code is working fine if I specify the date like this Apr 02 15:21:28, I mean if know time with exact min and second, But code gets failed with I pass value like this 
from Apr 02 15* to Apr 04 15* here 15 is hour, actually I want to make script in which user just need to add day and time (only in hours no min or seconds)

```
> #!/bin/bash
read -p " enter the App name : " app
file="/logs/$app/$app.log"
read -p " Enter the Date in this Format --'10 Jan 20 or Jan 10 20' : " first
read -p " Enter the End time of logs : " end

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
    if grep -q "$first" "$file"; then
        final_first=$first
    fi
    if grep -q "$end" "$file"; then
        final_end=$end
    fi

        sed -n " /$final_first/,/$final_end/ "p $file >$app.txt

else
        echo "$app.log not found, Please check correct log name in deployer"
fi
```

Sample data:

```
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel
```

Comment: Try to pass the value as just `Apr 02 15`, without an asterisk. And be aware that this only works as long as there are matching entries in the log file -- if nothing happened on April 2nd between 15:00 and 16:00, the range will never match.

Comment: @Wintermute yes you are correct I just pass Apr 02 15 and Apr 04 15, Here sed found first date but not Apr 04 15, therefore he extracted all the lines till end of logs file that is Apr 06 ... could you please tell any code which can be good replacement of this , I mean if don't find Apr 04 15 at least he can stop on Apr 04 not going beyond Apr 05

Comment: You need a tool which knows that `01 May 03` is later than `30 Apr 22`, and sed isn't that smart. I would use Perl, but you may prefer shell scripts.

Comment: Include some sample lines from a log file, so we can see the exact format of the time stamps.

Comment: @glennjackman I updated my code, what I am trying to do in this if any .. if condition fails it should put null value to sed final first and final end variable and sed command will not work in this case.

Comment: @ManishTiwari, commented in my answer

Comment: @glennjackman one more query, read -p " enter the App name : " app
file="/logs/$app/$app.log" here I face one challenge, actually few application log name didn't match with application name like /logs/FSEVisualizer/fseVisualizer.log so is there any way like "- i app" which can contain case in sensitive input from user

Comment: `declare -l app; read app` will store the user's input in lower case. From a bash prompt, read `help declare`

Comment: @glennjackman but see in this case if FSEVisualizer is read in lower case like fsevisualizer still then it not correct coz here we have one letter in upper case  fseVisualizer.log

Comment: Well, you'll have to educate your users, and loop until they enter a correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a language with built-in datetime parsing or an easily included module. For example, perl

```
first="Apr 07 12" 
end="Apr 08 00"
perl -MTime::Piece -sane '
    BEGIN {
        $first_ts = Time::Piece->strptime($first, "%b %d %H")->epoch;
        $end_ts = Time::Piece->strptime($end, "%b %d %H")->epoch;
    }
    $ts = Time::Piece->strptime(join(" ", @F[0..2]), "%b %d %T")->epoch;
    print if $first_ts <= $ts and $ts <= $end_ts;
' -- -first="$first" -end="$end" <<END

Apr 07 11:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:00:00 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel 
Apr 07 23:59:59 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel 
Apr 08 00:00:01 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel 
END
```

outputs

```
Apr 07 12:00:00 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] model.DSSAuthorizationModel - pathInfo : /about-ses 
Apr 07 12:39:15 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel 
Apr 07 23:59:59 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8089-21] servlet.CasperServlet - Request about to be serviced by model: com.ge.oilandgas.sts.model.SessionValidModel
```

---

Given your code, I would make the following change:

```
if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$app.log not found, Please check correct log name in deployer"
    exit 1
fi

grep -q "$first" "$file" && final_first="/$first/" || final_first='1'
grep -q "$end"   "$file" && final_end="/$end/"     || final_end='$'

sed -n "${final_first},${final_end}p" "$file" >"$app.txt"
```

That provides default addresses for the sed range, first line and last line.